# Getting text inside table

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I have a table like that. And I wanna get the just text FOO COMPANY from between td tags. How can I get it?

```
<table class="left_company">
    <tr>
        <td style="BORDER-RIGHT: medium none; bordercolor="#FF0000" align="left" width="291" bgcolor="#FF0000">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="103%" border="0">
                <tr style="CURSOR: hand" onclick="window.open('http://www.foo.com')">
                    <td class="title_post" title="FOO" valign="center" align="left" colspan="2">
                        <font style="font-weight: 700" face="Tahoma" color="#FFFFFF" size="2">***FOO COMPANY***</font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

I'm using following code but nS is null.

```
doc = hw.Load("http://www.foo.aspx?page=" + j);
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='left_company']"))
{
nS = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='title_post']");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var text = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                .FirstOrDefault(n => n.Attributes["class"] != null && 
                                n.Attributes["class"].Value == "title_post")
                .Element("font").InnerText;
```

or

```
var text2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='title_post']/font")
               .First().InnerText;
```

Answer (score 1):

Likely the page you are calling generate the content of interest using JavaScript.  HtmlAgilityPack does not execute JavaScript, so the content cannot be extracted.  One way to confirm this is to try to visit the page with scripting turned off, and try to see if the element you are interested in still exists.

Comment: Javascript just open a page man. I don't think it's about js.

Answer (score 0):

Close: `nS = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='title_post']//text()");`

You can then open the nS node to retrieve the text. If there's more than one text node, you'll need to iterate over them.

Answer (score 0):

insert some attribute to font element like company="FOO"

then use jquery to get that element like

```
alert($('font[company="FOO"]').html())
```

like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hhxuH/)

cheers